# OAuth2 Proxy with OpenID Connect Provider provider fails with "Error redeeming code during OAuth2 callback: could not verify id_token…"

Tags: authentication, oauth-2.0, openid-connect

I am having trouble making [OAuth2 Proxy](https://oauth2-proxy.github.io/oauth2-proxy/) work with my authorization server (an OpenID Connect Provider implemented by [LemonLDAP::NG](https://lemonldap-ng.org)).

I want to add SSO authentication to an existing simple web app without implementing auth in the app (can't really alter the code of the application).

The user accessing the app's URL (https://my-app.example.com) is displayed the "please login" page from OAuth2 Proxy with a button that redirects to the login page of the authorization server (on https://auth.example.com).

But once logged-in and after giving it's consent the user is redirected back to OAuth2 Proxy where it gets an error message:

> 500
> Internal Server Error
>
> More Info:
> could not verify id_token: failed to verify token: failed to verify signature: failed to verify id token signature
> Request ID: 543ed244-8197-4054-a52b-d1e3973eb73c

OAuth2 Proxy logs confirm the error, adding it's about code redeeming:

> Error redeeming code during OAuth2 callback: could not verify id_token: failed to verify token: failed to verify signature: failed to verify id token signature

I tried disabling `code_challenge_method` or changing it to `plain` without success.

How can I debug the received code?

I also noticed that the authorization server was receiving a `POST /oauth2/token` followed by a `GET /oauth2/jwks` from OAuth2 Proxy (see full logs below).

This authorization server is also used for authentication with other OpenID Connect compatible applications (such as Mattermost) and, whith theses the authorization server receives a `POST /oauth2/token` followed by a `GET /oauth2/userinfo` (not `/oauth2/jwks`).

It this a sign of misconfiguration?

Here is my OAuth2 Proxy configuration file for [`oidc` provider](https://oauth2-proxy.github.io/oauth2-proxy/docs/configuration/oauth_provider#openid-connect-provider) (I am running it locally for test):

```toml
http_address = "127.0.0.1:80"
https_address = "127.0.0.1:443"

tls_cert_file = "/etc/ssl/certs/ssl-cert-snakeoil.pem"
tls_key_file = "/etc/ssl/private/ssl-cert-snakeoil.key"

redirect_url = "https://my-app.example.com/oauth2/callback"

# Using the very simple web site https://perdu.com as an example upstream for tests:
upstreams = [
    "https://perdu.com"
]

whitelist_domains = [
    ".example.com",
    "my-app.example.com",
    "perdu.com"
]

ssl_upstream_insecure_skip_verify = true

email_domains = [
    "*"
]
insecure_oidc_allow_unverified_email = true

provider = "oidc"

oidc_issuer_url = "https://auth.example.com"

oidc_email_claim = "email"

client_id = "my-app"
client_secret = "my-app-secret"

code_challenge_method = "S256"

ssl_insecure_skip_verify = true

cookie_name = "_oauth2_proxy"
cookie_secret = "3Wvi9Yv0YOsU4GNvldd9bRSUfNW6u9P_WPxjPAipZB0="
cookie_domains = ".example.com"
cookie_samesite = "lax"
cookie_expire = "168h"
cookie_refresh = "4h"
cookie_httponly = false
cookie_csrf_per_request = true

show_debug_on_error = true
```

Relying Party configuration on LemonLDAP::NG side ([documentation](https://lemonldap-ng.org/documentation/2.0/idpopenidconnect.html)):

- OpenID Connect claims:

  - `email`
  - `id`
  - `preferred_username`
  - `username`
- Basic options:

  - Client ID: my-app
  - Client secret: my-app-secret
  - Public client: true
  - Redirection addresses :

    - https://my-app.example.com
    - https://my-app.example.com/oauth2/callback
- Advanced options:

  - Bypass consent: false
  - User attribute: *(none/empty)*
  - Force claims to be returned in ID Token: false
  - Use JWT format for Access Token: false
  - Release claims in Access Token: false
  - Additional audiences: *(none/empty)*
  - Use refresh tokens: false
- Security options:

  - ID Token signature algorithm: HS512
  - Access Token signature algorithm: RS256
  - Userinfo response format: JSON
  - Require PKCE: false
  - Allow offline access: false
  - Allow OAuth2.0 Password Grant: false
  - Allow OAuth2.0 Client Credentials Grant: false
  - Authentication Level: *(none/empty)*
  - Access Rule: *(none/empty)*
- Timeouts options:

  - Authorization Code expiration: *(none/empty)*
  - ID Token expiration: *(none/empty)*
  - Access token expiration: *(none/empty)*
  - Offline session expiration: *(none/empty)*

Full OAuth2 Proxy logs:

> `127.0.0.1:48784 - d51481a0-c867-4a71-ba6d-8ea595380af4 - - [2023/03/31 11:55:21] my-app.example.com GET - "/oauth2/start?rd=%2F%3F" HTTP/1.1 "Firefox" 302 422 0.000`
> `[2023/03/31 11:55:22] [oauthproxy.go:823] Error redeeming code during OAuth2 callback: could not verify id_token: failed to verify token: failed to verify signature: failed to verify id token signature`
> `127.0.0.1:48784 - 543ed244-8197-4054-a52b-d1e3973eb73c - - [2023/03/31 11:55:22] my-app.example.com GET - "/oauth2/callback?code=515c…fa38&session_state=335f…QkE9&state=M631…rt_I%3A%2F%3F" HTTP/1.1 "Firefox" 500 2872 0.127`
> `[2023/03/31 11:55:22] [oauthproxy.go:959] No valid authentication in request. Initiating login.`

Full HTTP LemonLDAP::NG access.log:

> `2.2.2.2 - - [31/Mar/2023:11:57:27 +0200] "GET /oauth2/authorize?approval_prompt=force&client_id=my-app&code_challenge=-RQC…ffdc&code_challenge_method=S256&redirect_uri=https%3A%2F%2Fmy-app.example.com%2Foauth2%2Fcallback&response_type=code&scope=openid+email+profile&state=M631…rt_I%3A%2F%3F HTTP/1.1" 302 5 "https://my-app.example.com/" "Firefox"`
> `2.2.2.2 - my-app [31/Mar/2023:11:57:27 +0200] "POST /oauth2/token HTTP/1.1" 200 623 "-" "Go-http-client/1.1"`
> `2.2.2.2 - - [31/Mar/2023:11:57:27 +0200] "GET /oauth2/jwks HTTP/1.1" 200 749 "-" "Go-http-client/1.1"`
> `2.2.2.2 - - [31/Mar/2023:11:57:27 +0200] "POST / HTTP/1.1" 200 107 "https://auth.example.com/" "Firefox"`

Note: Using OAuth2 Proxy version 7.4.0.